# Run OS native commands VS Python's in Fabric

Tags: python, command, fabric

I'm using Fabric for project management, deployment, etc. I don't really understand the more convenient way to run commands. For example, considering I don't care of `capture` and `shell` arguments of Fabric `local` function, which are pros/cons of the following?

```
os.mkdir(path)
```

VS

```
local("mkdir %s" % path)
```

Comment: I'd say `local("mkdir %s" % path)` is less robust because you are not handling paths with spaces and/or strange characters, while `os.mkdir` should handle them automatically.
But I do not know if this matters to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the goals of your project, either may be slightly more appropriate. Here are some pros and cons.

- Pros for python standard library functions

  - cross platform compatible
  - usually more efficient since no child process is created
  - overall less complex as involve fewer modules, processes, moving parts, shell parsing, etc (therefore easier to debug as well)
- Pros for fabric `local`

  - easier to switch between `local` and `run` or `sudo` as your project changes
  - more consistent with `run` and `sudo`

I think simple `local` commands that can easily be represented using standard library functions should be written just using the standard library as a default choice due to lower complexity. Case by case, I'd ask myself which is more likely: running this `fabfile.py` program on different OSes or converting this command from a local to a remote command and then code as calls to `local` if the latter is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Using OS native commands means you can pass them as arguments to both `local` and `run`. This is both more consistent and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Some good points are [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442078/), but methinks one more advantage for using `local` (and friends) is so that non-Python people can more easily see what is going on.